# Boas Práticas de teste

Tags: testes

Quais são as boas práticas quando o assunto é teste de software com relação a entrada e saída de arquivos? Existe alguma maneira eficaz adotada no mercado?É bom vir com algum conhecimento prévio, ou é melhor fazer o teste tendo o papel do próprio usuário, sem saber como o sistema irá reagir?

Comment: Isso incluí testes automatizados?

Comment: Clarissa Lippi tente esclarecer o que pretende com a pergunta, deixo uma alternativa: "Quais são os tipos de testes de software que se pode fazer com relação a entrada e saída de arquivos?". Se é que é mesmo essa a sua dúvida.

Answer (score 3):

Existem vários tipos de teste que você pode fazer:

- **Teste de Unidade:** Teste em um nível de componente ou classe. É o teste cujo objetivo é um “pedaço do código”. Exemplo: Testar seus métodos de gravam e recuperam um arquivo.
- **Teste de Performance:** Verifica se o tempo de resposta é o desejado para o momento de utilização da aplicação. Exemplo: Testar se o tempo de resposta ao gravar e recuperar um arquivo é satisfatório.
- **Teste de Carga:** Verifica o funcionamento da aplicação com a utilização de uma quantidade grande de usuários simultâneos. Exemplo: Testar a performance quando vários usuários gravando e/ou recuperando arquivos simultaneamente.
- **Teste de Volume:** Testar a quantidade de dados envolvidos (pode ser um arquivo pequeno, médio, grande, ou muito grande).
- **Teste funcional:** Testar os requisitos funcionais, as funções e os casos de uso. Exemplo: Testar se a aplicação faz o que deveria fazer quando o usuário grava/recuperar o arquivo.
- **Teste de Interface:** Verifica se a navegabilidade e os objetivos da tela onde o usuário vai gravar/recuperar um arquivo no sistema, funcionam como especificados e se atendem da melhor forma ao usuário.

Outra questão que pode ser importante é a segurança para salvar esses arquivos. Exemplo: Testar acesso caso o usuário precisa salvar/recuperar esse arquivo em um diretório X.